# Checking divisibility of $C^{20}_7-C^{20}_8 +C^{20}_9 -C^{20}_{10}+\dots-C^{20}_{20}$

Tags: binomial-theorem

Let $N=C^{20}_7-C^{20}_8 +C^{20}_9 -C^{20}_{10}+\dots-C^{20}_{20}$. Prove that it is divisible by $3,4,7,19$.

Comment: It is also divisible by $17$

Comment: Please add more context to this problem.  For example, why does it interest you?  What does it relate to among topics you've studied?  Can you think of an approach to answer it, even if perhaps it is one that poses difficulty?

Answer (score 3):

Hint. Since by the binomial theorem 
$$0=(1-1)^{20}=\sum_{n=0}^{20}\binom{20}{n}(-1)^n=\sum_{n=0}^{6}\binom{20}{n}(-1)^n+\sum_{n=7}^{20}\binom{20}{n}(-1)^n=\sum_{n=0}^{6}\binom{20}{n}(-1)^n-N$$
it follows that 
\begin{align*}
N&=\sum_{n=0}^6\binom{20}{n}(-1)^n\\
&=1-20+190-\frac{20\cdot 19\cdot 18}{3!}+\frac{20\cdot 19\cdot 18\cdot 17}{4!}-\frac{20\cdot 19\cdot 18\cdot 17\cdot 16}{5!}+\frac{20\cdot 19\cdot 18\cdot 17\cdot 16}{6!}\\
&=-19+19\cdot 10-20\cdot 19\cdot 3+5\cdot 19\cdot 3\cdot 17- 19\cdot 3\cdot 17\cdot 16+19\cdot 17\cdot 8\cdot 15.
\end{align*}
Is it $N$ divisible by $19$ (without evaluating all these product)?

What about $3$, $4$, and $7$?

Comment: how is $n$ equal to the first 7 terms?

Comment: @SakethMalyala: Note the $0=(1-1)^{20}$ part in Robert's answer, especially the zero

Comment: @SakethMalyala not $n$ but $N$.  In general the sum of ${m \choose k}(-1)^k$ over some $k$ is the negative of the the sum over the other $k$ in $\{0,1,2,\ldots m\}$

Comment: ahh i see. thank you! @Henry

Comment: @Saketh Malyala I edited with a few more details. Is it clear now?

Comment: yes, i totally get it now. :))